# Is there a FileType name for files without suffix in vim?

Tags: vim

With my current knowledge, I can use commands such as `autocmd FileType markdown colorscheme zen` to set a colorscheme for a particular type of file.
I have a need to use a colorscheme for all those files without a suffix, e.g., `no_suffix_file`.

I did some research online, but didn't find relevant information.
Perhaps there is a name for this kind of file in vim, or at least a name for all the other files that are not in vim's `FileType detector range`.

What is it?

Comment: The filetype detection is not only filename, but also content depended. Is the content of your files special (distinct header, ...)? Maybe you can introduce a new filetype for your files.

Comment: @jofel, I've got an acceptable answer in this same question on SO main-site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129775/is-there-a-filetype-name-for-files-without-suffix-in-vim/31131957#31131957

Answer (score 0):

In vim `:echo &ft` results nothing in a file without suffix. So there isn't a type for files without suffix. But what you could do is set a default colorscheme for all files (including files without suffix) and then with autocmd set different colorscheme for files with certain types

Comment: It is true, that a new file has no filetype. You need to run `:filetype detect` or reopen to trigger the filetype detection. The filetype detection is not only filename sensitive but also uses the content of a file. In this sense, your answer is not 100% correct.

Comment: op asked for a solution for files without suffix. I assumed that this means any kind of files without suffix.